# The menu icon on my raspbian Desktop is gone

Tags: raspbian

I was stirring in the order in which the objects are in the taskbar, until it unintentionally deletes the menu. Soon I added it again, I noticed that nothing was appearing but a blank spacing that when i hovered over it, it seems to be responsive, when I clicked, it opened the menu. The space was a few pixels wide, until in his preferences, I adjusted the "padding" to 1, and then it stayed at normal size for the menu. I saw that the directory for the menu icon was in "/usr/share/lxpanel/images/my-computer.png", and then I changed the path to where the standard Raspberry Pi OS icon was, but it literally didn't change anything.

Comment: `i already have try to modify he in menu settings` ... that information is not useful ... what did you try? ... what were you doing that caused the icon to disappear?

Comment: I edited the post, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Some background: I tried a couple of themes and eventually wiped out my menu icon also.

The default theme directory is: /usr/share/icons/PiXflat/24x24/places/
( The 24x24 may be 32x32, or 48x48 )

The links

> distributor-logo.png
> start-here.png
> gnome-main-menu.png

are links to

> rpi-logo.png in the same directory.

If you've changed themes, look in the current theme directory for these links and files. You might have to create them. (I did.)
Hope this helps someone.